# Python tkinter text widget insert slowing down

Tags: python, text, tkinter, widget, tk-toolkit

I'm having an issue with tkinter text widgets. Basically, I'm trying to write output to two different text widgets. Over time, output to the boxes slows down, and text starts outputting on multiple lines.

I have some python code here you can run if you want to observe

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread
from threading import Timer
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import queue
import serial



threadqueue = queue.Queue()
processqueue = Queue()
data = True

class MainGui():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Test")
        self.root.geometry("1280x1024")
        self.root["bg"] = "gray55"
        self.o_box()
        self.f_o_data_box()
        self.read_serial()
        self.root.mainloop()


    def o_box(self):
        self.serialbox = Text(self.root,
                          bg="black",
                          fg="white",
                          height=10,
                          width=105)
        self.serialbox.place(x=10, y=780)

    def f_o_data_box(self):
        self.faultdata = Text(self.root,
                          bg="gray93",
                          fg="red",
                          height=61,
                          width=65)
        self.faultdata.place(x=780, y=13)



    def run(self):
        pass



    def update_gui(self):
        self.root.update()


    def read_serial(self):
        try:
            self.serialbox.insert(CURRENT, str(processqueue.get()).encode('ascii'))
            self.faultdata.insert(CURRENT, str(processqueue.get()).encode('ascii'))
            self.serialbox.see("end")
            self.faultdata.see("end")
            self.root.after(10, self.read_serial)
        except queue.Empty:
            self.root.after(100, self.read_serial)






def run():

        ser = serial.Serial()
        while 1:
            processqueue.put(str("Hello").encode('ascii'))
            continue


def main():
    try:

        SerialProcess = Process(target=run)
        SerialProcess.start()

        MainWindow = MainGui();

        MainWindow.run();

        SerialProcess.join()


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My guess is that, for some reason, multiple text boxes are being instantiated on top of eachother or something... hence the output is slowing down over time and the output behavior gets strange. But I can't track down the source of the behavior. Can anyone explain why this is happening, or where my issues are? I've tried looking at the behavior of tk(), mainloop(), and tried to find instances in my code where I'm calling a new window repeatedly... none of which I've had any luck noticing.

I'm fairly new to python, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the text widget has performance issues with very long lines. Does the data you are inserting have newlines in it? It looks like it doesn't in this program.

Comment: Not right now, it doesn't.

Comment: Is there a better method to use?

Comment: There are no tkinter widgets that are appropriate for displaying thousands of characters without a line break. This is simply not something it was designed to do.

Comment: I have a version that does it with line breaks, same behavior. I can't find any documentation that implies it's not something it can do, so I assume I'm doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Have you considered adding debug statements or use a profiler to figure out where the slowdown is? Maybe your loops to read are taking too much time.

Comment: I don't think this is related, but maybe: why are you inserting text at `CURRENT` rather than the start or end? Perhaps the slowdown is related to having to calculate the index on every insert.